# TailwindCSS how to add first and last pseudo classes

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have some `<div>`-elements in my `vue`-application where I want to add to some `pseudo-classes` for displaying some borders. I use `tailwindcss`-version 1.9. Now I want to add `first:border-t-0` and `last:border-b-0` - but for a reason I don't know, it does not work.

Here is the markup

```
<div class="container flex flex-col" v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <div class="border-t-0 border-b-2 first:border-t-2 last:border-b-0">...some content</div>
</div>
```

in my `tailwind.config.js` I have added this after reading the [docs](https://v1.tailwindcss.com/docs/pseudo-class-variants#first-child):

```
module.exports = {
  variants: {
    borderWidth: ['first', 'last'],
  },
}
```

Can someone meybe tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[TailwindCSS v2.2.0](https://blog.tailwindcss.com/tailwindcss-2-2#before-and-after-variants) now supports styling pseudo-elements. If you are using an older version however there are [plugins](https://github.com/croutonn/tailwindcss-pseudo-elements) you can use, or you can also create a reusable component

```
const BorderedDiv= ({ index, content}) => (
  <div classNames="relative ">
    <div className="text-gray-300 absolute" >
     {content}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```